# How do I create a nested javascript object setting the property names dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a javascript callback function which queries my database using a set of parameters. The parameters are set using an object. How can I set the name of one of the properties dynamically?

Right now I have them all just written out. It works fine, it's just a little long. I just need to change the value of two property names. Where propertyNameToChange is in my example code.

```
var paramToChange = { /* I need to change the name of this property */
    propertyNameToChange: { /* And the name of this property */
      url: { 
        ComparisonOperator: 'EQ',
        AttributeValueList: [{
          S: alreadySetWithVar /* This is already set using a var */
        }]
      }
    },
    TableName: 'ximoRep',
    IndexName: 'url-index'
  }
.... // I have about 10 of these written out. Then my callback function queries using an array using the var name for the object.

var params = [paramOne, paramTwo, paramThree, paramFour, paramFive, paramSix, paramSeven, paramEight];
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascript does not have a means of changing the name of a property.  What you can do is to assign one property to another new property name and then delete the original property.

If you have this data structure:

```
var data = {
    prop1: {greeting: "hello"}
};
```

And, you want to change `prop1` to `otherProp`, you can do it like this:

```
data.otherProp = data.prop1;
delete data.prop1;
```

This assigns the value of the original property to a new property and then removes the original property.

The end result is:

```
var data = {
    otherProp: {greeting: "hello"}
};
```

---

A general purpose function for doing this that would even work with propeties that have special characteristics such as getters, setters or other custom attributes would use a propertyDescriptor like this:

```
function renameProp(obj, oldPropName, newPropName) {
    var descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, oldPropName);
    Object.defineProperty(obj, newPropName, descriptor);
    delete obj.oldPropName;
}
```

This assumes the `oldPropName` property is configurable and the object isn't frozen.

Comment: It's probably best to use `propertyDescriptors` when possible

Comment: @PitaJ - that extra complication is useful if you think the properties have special attributes.  If they're just regular properties, then there's no need.

Comment: I was just talking in the general sense. A more general solution would require the use of `propertyDescriptors` to really cover all of the angles.

Comment: @PitaJ - yeah, I agree.  Just not needed for just a bunch of data.

Comment: @PitaJ - I added a function that uses a property descriptor.

Answer (score 2):

```
paramToChange['newPropName'] = paramToChange['propertyNameToChange'];
delete paramToChange['propertyNameToChange'];
```

Fixed.